# How can I handle two keys, each with their own intervals, in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

How do I make it so if I have the space bar and the "a" key held down at the same time, the player moves left (the effect of pressing the a key) every 10 milliseconds and shoots (the effect of pressing the space bar) every 1000 milliseconds? Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track time for each of moving and shooting separately, and then when you check for the relevant keys, only allow the action if it happened far enough in the past.

```
now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
if pressed(K_A) and now - when_moved > 10:
    when_moved = now
    move_left()
if pressed(K_SPACE) and now - when_shot > 1000:
    when_shot = now
    shoot()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have never thought to use the time.get_ticks() method!

Comment: This works but the player stops moving whenever it shoots. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Check to make sure your key-pressed logic can handle multiple keys. Be sure to use separate `if` statements rather than `elif`.